# Docker file COPY then WORKDIR, but the file is in different directory

Tags: java, python, bash, docker

I have two docker images: **imageA** and **imageB**.

ImageA `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY ./target/java-app.jar /java-application/
```

ImageB `Dockerfile`

```
FROM imageA

# Install Python.
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ./startPythonServiceAndJavaApp.sh
```

**startPythonServiceAndJavaApp.sh** - is the scrip to start both java app and python app.

```
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ./java-application/java-app.jar & python app.py;
```

Then I build **imageA** - `docker build -t imageA .`. It builds successfully.

Then I build **imageB** and start the container. The python app starts **successfully**, but I get error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ./java-application/java-app.jar
```

When I ssh to the running container (note, it is running), I go into `app` directory. I ran `ls` and I saw these files:

```
C:\Users\user>docker exec -it 12345  bash
root@12345:/app# ls
Dockerfile  app.py  deploy.sh  requirements.txt  java-app.jar  startPythonServiceAndJavaApp.sh
```

My question, why did **java-app.jar** end up in the **app** directory? In the `Dockerfile` of the **imageA** I told it to be in `java-application` directory:

```
COPY ./target/java-app.jar /java-application/
```

Answer (score 0):

My question can be rephrased `COPY` and `WORKDIR` together. As a quick solution, I put the jar file into root of the docker context. Then I started both application from that context.

Here are the changes:

**ImageA** `Dockerfile` - just copy to the root of container.
    COPY ./target/java-app.jar /

**startPythonServiceAndJavaApp.sh**
java -XX:+UseContainerSupport $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ./java-app.jar & python app.py;

Both applications are running now in the single container. Hope this will help others. Please, correct me if I am wrong or share your ideas.